# SSH Ubuntu 19.10 weird ssh behaviour rejecting key after first login

Tags: server, ssh, 19.10, docker, raspberrypi

I have a respberry pi 4 with Ubuntu 19.10 x64 installed. I have ssh setup the same way I have done with every other Ubuntu server I have (No password login). My keys are appended correctly to authorized_keys and my key works everywhere else.

However I'm having an issue which I cannot figure out. I can ssh in once to the Rpi4. If I try to ssh in again I get a warning that the host key has changed and then my key gets rejected. All of my devices have static IPs and nothing else is conflicting with that IP

Has anyone encountered this or have a work around as it's frying my head!!

UPDATE:

So I have narrowed it down to occurring only when the Rpi4 is joined into the docker swarm as a worker. Once I leave the swarm ssh starts working as normal. Not sure why this is and its the first time I've seen this happen.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the Pi `etc/ssh/sshd_config`  has `PasswordAuthentication yes`

If the statement looks like this:

```
Offending key for IP in /home/fitzPi/.ssh/known_hosts:14
```

Try commenting # out the 14th line in the file or delete it completely

sed -i '14d' ~/.ssh/known_hosts

Now reboot or `sudo service ssh restart` check here `sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log` before trying to setup keys again.